# Are questions about the weight of a specific bike too localized?

Tags: discussion, too-localized

We've recently got a couple questions asking about the weight of specific bikes.

Assuming that the question is answerable (just asking about frame and fork, not components and has enough information about the frame they're asking about), are these questions too localized?

Too localized official description:

> This question is unlikely to ever help any future visitors; it is only relevant to a small geographic area, a specific moment in time, or an extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet.

Example questions:

- [1985 Trek 720 Weight](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/8616/1985-trek-720-weight)
- [How much does a Toei weigh?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/8583/how-much-does-a-toei-weigh)

Answer (score 3):

I believe they are too specific to be relevant in both those cases. However, a great deal of that lack of relevancy is due to the lack of common availability, and possibly the current level of desire for those particular bikes.

If someone was asking about the weight of a new Storck Fascenario 0.6, or the new Madone, I might not think it was too localized, because I believe more people might want or need that information.

I do think that there are easily available sources for that type of data, which do not require questions here.

Comment: I agree with this; all I can add is that both of these questions would be much better if they were changed to, "how do I find out the weight of a hard-to-locate bike?" These questions are just fishing expeditions, as the real answer is "call the company" or "find one and weigh it." If you want to ask "who has one of these handy," go to a forum.

Comment: Also, the likelihood of someone having the exact bike and frame size to weigh is remote at best. They end up filling the "Unanswered" category.